# alert for Ichimoku setup in diffrent timeframes

Tags: alert, pine-script

Hi I am new to Pine and would like tyo ask if it possible with Pine to write a program that sends me an alert when in ichimoku indicator, the conversion line is above the baseline on the 4 hr, 1 hr, 15min and 5 min timeframe? If yes, where can I find some sample code pls? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `request.security()` to get data from higher timeframes.

You can modify the original code. Something like below:

```
baseLine_1h = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", baseLine[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
baseLine_4h = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", baseLine[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

is_buy = (conversionLine > baseLine_1h) and (conversionLine > baseLine_4h)
alertcondition(is_buy, "Buy")
```

Comment: Hi vitruvius I used your code but then I get a warning that alert may trigger differently because it is based on an indicator that or strategy that can get repainted. Is there some code you recommend that solve sthis error pls?

Comment: It is a warning not an error. The piece of code I shared here will not cause any repainting issues.